# Converting XML in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem. I have 2 files. First file data.php:

```
<?php
$str = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Radio</name>
        <price>79.99</price>
        <desc>Place for describe</desc>
    </product>
        <product>
        <name>TV</name>
        <price>599.99</price>
        <desc>Place for describe</desc>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Book</name>
        <price>75.00</price>
        <desc>Place for describe</desc>
    </product>
<products>'; 

?>
```

And the second file index.php:

```
<?php
include('data.php');

$products =new SimpleXMLElement($str);

foreach($products->product as $product){
echo $product->name;
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

I use Wamserver. When i try to run index.php in web Browser I get errors:
http://zapodaj.net/images/fbd51b9ca6da9.jpg
I want to show name of each product. Can someone can tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your products end block is wrong, you forgot /

Pleas find correct xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Radio</name>
        <price>79.99</price>
        <desc>Place for describe</desc>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>TV</name>
        <price>599.99</price>
       <desc>Place for describe</desc>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Book</name>
        <price>75.00</price>
        <desc>Place for describe</desc>
    </product>
</products>
```

You can used this website to check your xml online : http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the XML is not valid, you need a closing tag at the end:

```
    </product>
</products>';
```

(last lines of the file). The rest of the code seems ok.

Secondly, you should use

```
simplexml_load_string($str);
```

**Example** (with `php -a`):

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $str='<?xml version="1.0"?>
php ' <products>
php '     <product>
php '         <name>Radio</name>
php '         <price>79.99</price>
php '         <desc>Place for describe</desc>
php '     </product>
php '         <product>
php '         <name>TV</name>
php '         <price>599.99</price>
php '         <desc>Place for describe</desc>
php '     </product>
php '     <product>
php '         <name>Book</name>
php '         <price>75.00</price>
php '         <desc>Place for describe</desc>
php '     </product>
php ' </products>';
php > $products = simplexml_load_string($str);
php > foreach($products->product as $product){
php { echo $product->name;
php { echo "<br>";
php { }
Radio<br>TV<br>Book<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

As CommuSoft Says You Haven't Closed your XML block

```
</product>
</products>';
```

And you should use as CommuSoft says `simplexml_load_string($str);`
As you are storing your XML in a variable as a string.